# How can I use pandas to parse CSV already loaded from somewhere else?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-analysis

I download and scrape a webpage for some data in TSV format. Around the TSV data is HTML that I don't want.

I download the html for the webpage, and scrape out the data I want, using beautifulsoup.
However, I've now got the TSV data in memory.

How can I use this TSV data in memory with pandas? Every method I can find seems to want to read from file or URI rather than from data I've already scraped in.

I don't want to download text, write it to file, and then rescrape it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from pandas import pandas as p
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def main():
    url = "URL"
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # pre is the tag that the data is within
    tab_sepd_vals = soup.pre.string

    data = p.LOAD_CSV(tab_sepd_vals)
    process(data)
```

Comment: Can you read it directly with `pandas.read_html`? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#html

Comment: No, because pandas.read_html depends on bs4, and I'm using python2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feed the text/string version of the data into a `StringIO.StringIO` (or `io.StringIO` in Python 3.X), you can pass that object to the pandas parser. So your code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import pandas as p
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import StringIO

def main():
    url = "URL"
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # pre is the tag that the data is within
    tab_sepd_vals = soup.pre.string

    # make the StringIO object
    tsv = StringIO.StringIO(tab_sepd_vals)

    # something like this
    data = p.read_csv(tsv, sep='\t') 

    # then what you had
    process(data)
```

Comment: I hadn't come across StringIO before, so for those curious like me: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html - they allow strings to be used where files were expected.

Answer (score 1):

Methods like `read_csv` do two things, they parse the CSV and they [construct](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/e067b6108ce237d5f518fbdc0afb82ad6c3f58cf/pandas/io/parsers.py#L616) a `DataFrame` object - so in your case you might want to construct the [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) directly:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]])
>>> print(df)
   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
```

The constructor accepts a variety of data structures.

Comment: But I want a CSV parser too, just not the IO component.